# I don't understand what the code is suppose to do?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
module.exports = (client, message, args) => { 
  message.reply("Pong!");
}
```

What is it replying to? I really don't understand what the code is supposed to do cause it say's "message.reply" but what message is it supposed to reply to?

Comment: Any [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Message?scrollTo=reply) you feed it.

Comment: Traceback where `message` cones from.

Answer (score 0):

The message string from which was sent in a channel,

For example, if you sent "Hey, I am sending this message in this discord channel", is `message`

```
module.exports = (client, "message", args) => { 
...
}
```

and the `message` variable in `message.reply()` is the `message` variable from the `module.exports` function above.

And when you put all of that together, `message.reply("")` would respond to the message that was sent in a channel with the arguments you put inside of `.reply("");`.

Example:

`message.reply("Replying to this message");` would reply to the message that was sent in a channel, with the string of `"Replying to this message"`.